# Approach for optimization problem with polynomial constraints?

Tags: polynomials, discrete-optimization

I have a problem where the objective function is linear and constraints have polynomials (in one variable). So, my question is what are the main approaches to this issue? I can construct a small example, just to illustrate it.

$ \max \sum_{i} a_i x_i - \sum_{j} b_j y_j $

$\qquad c_1 x_i + c_2 x_i^2 + c_3 x_i^3 +\ldots + c_k x_i^k = \sum_{j} d_j y_j, \quad \forall i\in N  $

$\qquad x_i \geq 0, \quad i\in N $

$\qquad y_j \in \{0,1\}, \quad j\in M $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small scale problems, simply using a global solver appears to work very well, at least for the data I tried. Here is some YALMIP code (MATLAB Toolbox, developed by me) to solve a small instance using YALMIPs global solver bmibnb. It is solved in a second or so if you have a good MILP solver installed. Similiar with scips global solver

```
N = 10;
M = 20;
degree = 4;
a = randn(N,1);
b = randn(M,1);
c = rand(M,degree);
d = randn(M,1);

x = sdpvar(N,1);
y = binvar(M,1);
objective = a'*x - b'*y;
Model = x>=0
for i = 1:N
    Model = [Model, [-d'*y c(i,:)]*monolist(x(i),4) == 0];
end

optimize(Model,objective,sdpsettings('solver','bmibnb'))
value(x)
value(y)
%optimize(Model,objective,sdpsettings('solver','scip'))
```

EDIT: To follow up on your comment, here is a model based on a PWA approximation (using sos2 constructs in cplex, as that speeds up things). Of course, the bound 5 should be chosen more carefully by performing bound propagation etc. Solved in a fraction of a second, but the drawback is of course the lack of an exact solution

```
xi = linspace(0,5,200)';
Model = x>=0
for i = 1:N
    fi = c(i,1)*xi + c(i,2)*xi.^2 + c(i,3)*xi.^3 + c(i,4)*xi.^4;
    lambda = sdpvar(length(fi),1);
    Model = [Model,sos2(lambda)];
    Model = [Model, x(i) == lambda'*xi, d'*y == lambda'*fi,lambda>=0,sum(lambda)==1]; 
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to transform the polynomial constraints to quadratic, i.e. to reformulate the problem as MIQCP. But the question is, whether it would be useful at all? Will CPLEX/Gurobi outperform significantly, for example, Baron on medium instances? I ask that 'cause I don't have an opportunity to do the benchmark with some commercial MINLP software, and maybe someone already knows something. Also, I was wondering about piecewise approximation. I don't have experience with that, so maybe it is better to ask first.:)

Comment: You would not be able to use cplex to solve the problem exactly. You have nonconvex equalities, and they would still be after lifting the equations to quadratics (anything beyond affine equality is nonconvex)

Comment: Added a pwa model to the code